# in query Whats the error pls solve it

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following error

> insert into staff_service(customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date) values('1','414','2011-03-14',CURDATE()) 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_date) values('1','414','2011-03-14',CURDATE())' at line 1

```
<?php
session_start();

include "common/config.php";

    $file=file("Template/staffservice_management.html");
    $filecontent=join("",$file);
    include("user.php");
/*$sql = "SELECT id,customer_name FROM customer "."ORDER BY customer_name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['customer_name']."</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['customer_name']."</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['customer_name']."</option>";
}*/
$sql="select * from customer";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
     $list_option.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['customer_name']."</option>";
}
$cust=$_POST['cname'];
$work=$_POST['won'];
$date=$_POST['startdate'];
if($_REQUEST['submit']=='submit')
{
$sqle=("insert into staff_service(customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date) values('$cust','$work','$date',CURDATE())");
$Insertprocess=$db->insert_data_id($sqle);
echo "<script>alert(' Details Successfully created');</script>;";
echo "<script>location.href='staffservice_management.php';</script>;";
}
$filecontent=preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/e","$$1",$filecontent);
echo $filecontent;

?>
```

Comment: what is your mysql `current_date` data type?

Answer (score 1):

Don't interpolate variables straight into your SQL, you're asking for SQL injection attacks.  Take a look at http://www.bobby-tables.com/

As for the error, there's no space after the table name, that's the likely culprit; it's being treated as a call to an unknown function, `staff_service()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into staff_service (customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date) values('$cust','$work','$date',CURDATE())
```

**leave space after table name**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need an space between

**staff_service**

and

**(customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date)**

Try with:

```
$sqle=("insert into staff_service (customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date) values('$cust','$work','$date',CURDATE())");
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `" ' "` for numbers/ids:

```
insert into staff_service(customer_id,workorder_no, service_date,current_date) values(1,414,'2011-03-14',CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO staff_service
(customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date) 
VALUES ('1','414','2011-03-14',CURDATE())
```

There are a couple of questions about [Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html):

- What is the data type of customer_id?

  - if it is a INT data type, no need for the single quotes around the value 1

    - EXAMPLE: VALUES (1,'414','2011-03-14',CURDATE())
- What is the data type of workorder_no?

  - if it is a INT data type, no need for the single quotes around the value 414

    - EXAMPLE: VALUES ('1',414,'2011-03-14',CURDATE())
- What is the data type of service_date?

  - If it's a date/time type are you submitting the correct format?

    - [Other formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- What is the data type of current_date?

  - If it's a date/time type are you submitting the correct format?

    - [Other formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

You might want to end you SQL statement with a semicolon as well, like this:

```
INSERT INTO staff_service
(customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,current_date) 
VALUES ('1','414','2011-03-14',CURDATE());
```

My suggestions are to make sure you are passing the data in the correct format

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Add a semicolon at the end of the SQL query.</strike>

Comment: -1 for the fact that any PHP MySQL library acts as if there's a semi-colon at the end of query automatically.